# Function to return items from an array where items at odd index which are repeated by the number at its preceding even index

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

I got this interview question when interviewing with some big company. They asked me to write out a function `next`, which takes an array as the input value and returns the next available number.

The number at even index in the array indicates the number of the next number in the array at the odd index
. For example, `[2,2,1,7,3,5]` meaning that we have two `2`s, one `7` and 3 `5`s. So calling `next()` will output `2` `2` `7` `5` `5` `5` sequentially one at a time. And when there is no available number, in this case when the third `5` is returned, the function would throw exception.

So this question was quite open ended. They didn't explicitly specify how I should implement this function. The only requirement was to achieve the behavior mentioned above, i.e. output next available number one at time.

During the interview I thought it would make sense to put this function on the prototype chain of `Array` so we can call this function directly on an array like this

```js
const array = [2, 2, 1, 7, 3, 5];

Array.prototype.next = function() {
  const buffer = [];
  let x;
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      x = i;
    } else {
      buffer.push(...new Array(this[x]).fill(this[i]));
    }
  }
  return buffer[index++];
};

console.log(array.next()); // 2
console.log(array.next()); // 2
console.log(array.next()); // 2
```

I noticed that people are saying it's bad idea to make the function part of the `Array` prototype. So here is another solution

```js
function getNext(array) {
  const buffer = [];
  let x;
  let index = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      x = i;
    } else {
      buffer.push(...new Array(array[x]).fill(array[i]));
    }
  }
  return buffer[index++];
}
```

However the problem is, it doesn't remember the last output and move on to the next one. It will always output the first item in the array.

I always thought maybe we can implement this `next` as an iterator but I couldn't implement it myself.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: You're already half way to the iterator solution, all you need is to `return buffer[Symbol.iterator]()` instead of `buffer[0]`.

Comment: …however it sounds like they want you to mutate the array, i.e. decrement counts and remove the first tuple after taking the number.

Comment: Your code doesn't satisfy this condition : `which takes an array as the input`

Comment: @Eldar yea I know. As I said the question they asked was open-ended. it's up to you to decide the implementation details.

Comment: @Bergi Could you spend a couple mins to write out your solution? I'd really like to learn from other people's solutions

Comment: @Bergi I changed my return from `  return buffer[index++];` to `return buffer[Symbol.iterator]();` but it doesn't seem to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a natural fit for this problem would be a generator function. You can read more about them here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator

Here is my solution. Let me know if you have any questions:

```js
const generatorFunc = function* (arr) {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    yield arr[i];
    i++;
  } 
};

const buildIterator = (arr) => {
  const generatedArr = arr.reduce((acc, item, itemIndex) => {
    const isEven = itemIndex % 2 === 0;
    if (isEven) {
      const value = arr[itemIndex + 1];
      const iterationCount = item;
      return acc.concat(Array(iterationCount).fill(value));
    };
    return acc;
  }, []);
  const generator = generatorFunc(generatedArr);
  return {
    next: () => {
      const nextIteration = generator.next();
      if (nextIteration.done) {
        throw new Error('No more items in array');
      }
      return nextIteration.value;
    }
  };
};

const myIterator = buildIterator([2,2,1,7,3,5]);

console.log(myIterator.next()); //2
console.log(myIterator.next()); //2
console.log(myIterator.next()); //7
console.log(myIterator.next()); //5
console.log(myIterator.next()); //5
console.log(myIterator.next()); //5
console.log(myIterator.next()); // ERROR!!
```

There's a little bit of syntactic sugar here as standard js generator functions return objects like `{ value, done }`. Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. I am new to generator/iterator. Could you provide some instructions on how to run `myIterator` and get the result?

Comment: sure thing. `myIterator` returns an object with a `next` method. You would simply have to run `myIterator.next()` to return the next value in the sequence. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Could you elaborate a bit on “There's a little bit of syntactic sugar here as standard js generator functions return objects like { value, done }” I don't completely understand it. Also could you make the iterator throw exception when it is called when there's no available number?

Comment: Sure. When you call a Javascript Generator's `next`, it returns an object. It's why I added the `.value` at the end of `next: () => generator.next().value`. But to really understand js generators I encourage you to play with that `generatorFunc` I wrote.  I'll update the answer to throw an exception when done.

Comment: more on js generators: the egghead series is pretty good: https://egghead.io/courses/write-simple-asynchronous-code-with-javascript-generators

Answer (score 1):

Well you got the problem solving part. All you need to do is create a scope then preserve the array you created temporarly and the current index in that scope.

```js
const array = [2, 2, 1, 7, 3, 5];

function sequencer(arr) {
  const actualArray = []
  let currentIndex = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      x = i;
    } else {
      actualArray.push(...new Array(arr[x]).fill(arr[i]));
    }
  }
  return function() {
    if (currentIndex >= actualArray.length) throw new Error("execced array length")
    return actualArray[currentIndex++];
  }
}
let arrSequencer = sequencer(array);
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  console.log(arrSequencer());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I read the question again and it seems that this is iterator kind of question. I'll still leave my answer as is, since it gives the guideline (without recursion) on how to create the answer as well.

I'd approach it like this:

```js
const next = (arr) => {
  const [multiplier, number, ...rest] = arr;

  if (!number) {
    throw Error('No next number specified');
  }

  const currentOne = Array.from(Array(multiplier), () => number);
  const nextOne = (rest.length) ? next(rest) : [];
  return currentOne.concat(nextOne);
}

console.log(next([2,1,3,2,4,3]));
console.log(next([2,1,3,2,4,3,5]));
```

So basically we pick the multiplier and the number, spreading the rest of the array as such.

If we don't have the number specified, we throw an error. Otherwise we create a new array with length of multiplier and content of the number.

Then we make a recursive call with the rest of the array, if it contains any elements.

And finally we return the result.

**Edit**: You could use `Array(multiplier).fill(number)` instead of iterating it like in my example (`Array.from(Array(multiplier), () => number);`)

Comment: Nice solution. However it returns an array of nums at once, not returning them one at a time.